# How to access global variables when making use of multiproccesing in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I'm making use of different processes but I'm unable to make use of global variable. I have 2 processes, 1 how gather data from an api and the last process uses this data and does some calculations on the obtained data. I've followed this [article](https://blog.ruanbekker.com/blog/2019/02/19/sharing-global-variables-in-python-using-multiprocessing/) but it doesn't work for me. Can someone help me?

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing
import time

class Example():
    def __init__(self):
        manager = multiprocessing.Manager()

        self.curValues1 = manager.dict()

    def main(self):
        p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.gatherProcess1)
        p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.calc)
        p1.start()
        p2.start()
        p1.join()
        p2.join()

    def gatherProcess1(self):
        df = pd.DataFrame([['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]], columns = ['Name', 'Age'])  # Get data from api

        self.curValues1 = {"lastName": df["Name"].iloc[-1], "lastAge": df["Age"].iloc[-1]}

    def calc(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(self.curValues1["lastName"], self.curValues1["lastAge"])

example = Example()

example.main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to update `self.curValues1` dict in place, not re-assign it:

```py
self.curvalues1.update({"lastName": df["Name"].iloc[-1], "lastAge": df["Age"].iloc[-1]})
```

When you re-assign `self.curValues1` the way you currently do, you just throw away the `multiprocessing.Manager` `dict` and assign it to a regular `dict`.

Comment: Thanks! And how can I update a list without throwing away the `multiprocessing.Manager`  `list`?

Comment: @KobeJanssens Use `.append`/`.extend`/`.insert`/`.remove`/etc. as appropriate.